# Escaping special characters using CDATA in php

Tags: php, xml

this has kept me days. trying to output an xml with these values. The bottomline is that it works fine but not with special chars, i wanna escape using CDATA. I tried `$output .= '<name>'<![CDATA['.$_category->getName().']]>'</name>';` but shows no data. that means the method $_category->getName() does not run. The code below breaks when there is no CDATA.

```
       $output .= '<category>';
       $output .= '<name>'.$_category->getName().'</name>';
       $output .= '<url>'.$_category->getUrl().'</url>';
       $output .= '</category>';
```

Comment: Please define your problem a bit more. What output are you getting with *this* code?

Comment: @Jonathan M — *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['* of course, the string literal is malformed as the additional text has been added after the closing `'` and then another `'` has been appended after that.

Comment: @Quentin, yes that would be it for the first example, but the code block?

Comment: @Jonathan M — Since that makes no mention of CDATA and the question is "how to escape using CDATA?", it is presumably the "before" code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the literal text you want to send to the browser **inside the string** literal.

```
$output .= '<name><![CDATA[' . $_category->getName() . ']]></name>';
```

That said, don't try to build XML by smashing together strings, you're just asking for errors to be introduced by unexpected data. **Use a real XML library.**

Comment: I don't think he's trying to output the CDATA literal. But, then again, who can tell? +1 for the XML library suggestion.

Comment: @Jonathan M — What would be the point of having it if it wasn't supposed to end up in the generated XML?

Comment: I get what you're saying, but looking at his code, it seems...I dunno. Need more info.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguos question. I really wanna output the real values i get from the method. But @Quentin method shd work. I dnt get anything on the screen outputed